# Use closing parenthesis() as delimiters in multiple Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, string

how to use this closing  parenthesis ()  in this group of delimiters :

group one :

```
(?<=[-+*/%])
```

group tow :

```
(?=[-+*/%])
```

My code is :

```
 String str = " (31 + 4) -6+ 1 % 7";  

 String [] result = str.split("(?<=[-+*/%])|(?=[-+*/%]) " )  ;

 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

I want this closing parenthesis () act as other characters in brackets [] , 
with 
look-behind assertion

```
(?<=...)
```

and look-ahead assertion

```
 (?=...)
```

the output is :

```
   [ (31, +, 4), -, 6, +, 1, %, 7]
```

the output needed :

```
 [ (  , 31, +, 4 ,  ) , -, 6, +, 1, %, 7]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: just add `)` inside the char class.

Comment: Look for other tool to parse mathematical expression (a recursive descent implementation, or parser generator like antlr). Regex is not the proper tool to parse them - only lexing at most.

Comment: @anubhava this is output from code above _[ (31, +, 4), -, 6, +, 1, %, 7]_ but I want this output _[ ( , 31, +, 4 , ) , -, 6, +, 1, %, 7]_ >> the closing parenthesis is  same as the another characters.

Comment: @Avinash Raj dose not workn when add it

Comment: @safana: Like this: [`(?<=[-+*/%()])|(?=[-+*/%()])\\s*`](http://ideone.com/uaaNPA)?

Comment: Better to use this regex [`([-+*/%()]|\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sX2sO8/1) for matching.

Comment: @ stribizhev No , does not print  every term alone in the expression

Comment: @safana: What do you mean? The results are `[ , (, 31 , +,  4, ),  , -, 6, +,  1 , %,  7]`.

Comment: to keep operators  and operands as well as closing parenthesis in one  array , Each one of them individually in a cell . Which all in one String

Comment: @stribizhev mean ,even closing parenthesis in different place in an array

Comment: Have a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/uaaNPA): isn't it working as you expect? Result is `[(, 31 , +,  4, ), -, 6, +,  1 , %,  7]`.

Comment: @stribizhev  yes it is :) thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the round brackets to both the character classes you have can help you achieve what you need. To remove the empty (space-only) elements, you can use the post-processing with `.removeAll(Collections.singleton(" "))` run against an list of strings.

Thus, you can use the following code:

```
String s = " (31 + 4) -6+ 1 % 7";
String[] sp = s.split("(?<=[-+*/%()])|(?=[-+*/%()])\\s*");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sp));
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(" "));
System.out.println(list);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uaaNPA)

Another way mentioned by anubhava, with `[0-9]+|[-+*/%()]` regex that matches sequences of digits or the operators:

```
String s = " (31 + 4) -6+ 1 % 7";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[-+*/%()]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    res.add(matcher.group(0));
}
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZbbSah)